# How long do I have to wait to reenter the US?

Tags: usa

I stayed in the US for five months and came back. After one month I tried going back and they we're suspicious about my return to US. So they gave me one month and that was it. That total to six months which is the original amount of months I can stay there. The question now is how long do I have to wait till I can go back again in the US???

Comment: Did you come on a B1 visa ? A VWP allows you 90 days, where did you get your 6 months figure from ?

Comment: What were you doing in the US?  What is your citizenship?

Comment: Did you have a visitor visa? The expectation with such a visa is that that you will use it to, well, visit. Staying somewhere six out of seven months generally looks more like living in the US rather than visiting. It would help to know more about your visa situation and why you're coming to the US.

Comment: @ZachLipton but the standard allowance for a B visa is 6 months.  A six-month visit therefore can't be evidence in and of itself that someone is living in the US.

Comment: I have rejected an edit by an anon editor. If it was OP, please sign into your account or make a new account and ask for the two to be merged, before you edit the question again.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have a valid US B2 visa, you can travel to the US at any time.

Whether you are allowed to enter and how long a duration of stay you are always up to the immigration officer on each particular entry.

Comment: Ah, a dilemma.  The strict factual answer is, as you note, "not at all."  The real question, though, is "how long *should* I wait before returning to the US," and the answer is probably "it depends on how averse you are to risk."  With that, I'm afraid, the question is likely to be closed as "primarily opinion based."